# Splitting strings in multiple columns into multiple rows in R

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(Column1=c("1", "2", "3"), 
  Column2=c("craft1-craft2-craft3", "craft4-craft5", "craft6-craft7"), 
  Column3=c("order1,order2,order3", "order4,order5", "order6,order7"))
```

The df looks like this:

```
Column1      Column2                     Column3
1            craft1-craft2-craft3        order1,order2,order3
2            craft4-craft5               order4,order5,order6
3            craft6-craft7               order6,order7
```

The table I want in the end:

```
Column1      Column2                     Column3
1            craft1                      order1
1            craft2                      order2
1            craft3                      order3
2            craft4                      order4
2            craft5                      order5
3            craft6                      order6
3            craft7                      order7
```

bascially, I want each one in column2 corresponding to each one in column3.
`separate_rows()` function is not working, it will give me craft1 order1, craft1 order2, craft1 order3, etc.

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: How did you use `separate_rows` that didn't work? Also, the logic is unclear: why do you end up with only 2 rows for column1 = 2, if you have 3 orders?

Comment: Actually scratch that, I was looking at the example of what you said the data looks like, which seems to be incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Use `separate_rows` with multiple delimiters in `sep`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   separate_rows(c(Column2, Column3), sep = "[-,]")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  Column1 Column2 Column3
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 1       craft1  order1 
2 1       craft2  order2 
3 1       craft3  order3 
4 2       craft4  order4 
5 2       craft5  order5 
6 3       craft6  order6 
7 3       craft7  order7
```